# What is the easiest way to resolve conflicts on Github when doing a Pull Request

Tags: git, github, git-merge-conflict

I am trying to **merge** branches on **GitHub** via **Pull Request**, but I am getting **conflicts**.

What is the **easiest** way to solve the conflicts?

Comment: Voting as too broad.

Comment: @nullpointer GitHub just introduced this feature today, and I think this Q&A could be a good resource for the times to come.

Comment: Some repos prefer rebasing the branch so there are no conflicts when merging a pull request.

Comment: IMO - The question is based on the individual practices and is biased more onto advertising a feature than highlighting the usefulness of it.

Comment: @nullpointer, although I agree this is based on individual practices I highly doubt it's just to advertise GH. They're generally very good and open when it comes to stuff like this, and IME in the F/OSS community they like to let their work speak for itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use GitHub web editor.

[image]

2. You'll be presented with an editor, which will look like this:

[image]

Keep the changes that you want, and delete the rest (including the delimiters).

Assuming you want to keep the code from `foo` branch, this is how your code should look like after editing:

[image]

Using Prev and Next links, navigate to the next conflict:

[image]

Hit "Mark as Resolved", and optionally, repeat for other files:

[image]

Finally, when you're done resolving all files, a new button appears:

[image]

GitHub just introduced this new feature, and it simplifies resolving simple conflicts.

Docs are here: https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-on-github/